# Can a non-generic class implement a generic interface?

Tags: java, generics, interface

I've been reading "Java. A Beginner's Guide" by Herbert Schildt. In the section on generic interfaces on one page the author writes (emphasis mine):

> Any class that implements a generic interface **must itself be generic**.

And on the next page (emphasis mine):

> **In general**, if a class implements a generic interface, then **that class must also be generic**, at least to the extent that it takes a type parameter that is passed to the interface.

So are there any specific situations where a non-generic class can implement a generic interface in Java? Or all such classes are generic in that they 'inherit' that generality from the generic interface?

**UPD:** I should have read the section further. The author goes on to state:

> Of course, if a class implements a specific type of generic interface, such as shown here:
>   `class MyClass implements Containment<Double> {`
>   then the implementing class does not need to be generic.

This is, I believe, the gist of all the answers to my post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to create a non-generic class that implements a generic interface, provided that the type parameters are provided.

A relatively simplistic example:

```
public class LocalDateParser implements Function<String, LocalDate> {
    public LocalDate apply (String s) {
        return LocalDate.parse(s);
    }
}
```

Of course, you can only assign an instance of this class to `Function<String, LocalDate>`, and not to any other `Function<T, R>`.

Comment: Ah, so when a specific type of generic interface is implemented, the implementing class needn't be generic - ok. But if a type parameter is used in the interface declaration, then the class implementing the interface should also state it, right?

Comment: Any time a class or interface comes with type parameters, these should be provided.  Otherwise, it just leads to pain.  Relevant question: [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Answer (score 2):

I think the author is plain wrong in both statements. A generic class is a class that accepts a generic type parameter. And you can create a class that doesn't accept any generic type parameter that implements a generic interface:

```
public class CaseInsensitiveComparator implements Comparator<String> {

    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        return s1.compareToIgnoreCase(s2);
    }
}
```

<sub>In fact, this class already exists in the JDK, though it's implemented differently. Please see [`String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER) for further details.</sub>

Comment: I believe this is what Joe C. meant. I should have read the section further. The author goes on to state: "Of course, if a class implements a specific type of generic interface, [...] then the implementing  class does not need to be generic." So I believe it's a matter of semantic.

Comment: @JohnAllison *"**must** itself be generic"* is not just bad semantics. It's wrong! There are more cases of non-generic classes implementing generic interface, than there are generic classes implementing generic interfaces using the same arguments.

Answer (score 2):

The guide you're reading is wrong.

There are many examples of non-generic classes implementing generic interfaces.

The most common one is [`Comparable<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html). The Java 8 javadoc lists 152 implementing classes, few of which pass on a generic type argument to the interface, since they are all supposed to specify themselves as the argument to `Comparable`, e.g.

```
public final class String implements Serializable, Comparable<String>, CharSequence
```

```
public final class Integer extends Number implements Comparable<Integer>
```

```
public final class Instant implements Temporal, TemporalAdjuster, Comparable<Instant>, Serializable
```